# Transforming row data into columns. Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Seems like this should be fairly simple, but I've searched and searched and tried and tried for some time now and it's just beyond me.

I have a table named "Antenna_Electrical_Parameters" that looks like this:

Site ID   Antenna ID         Electrical Controller  Electrical Tilt

Site_106    3   Port 1-2    4

Site_106    3   Port 3-4    4

Site_106    4   Port 1-2    1

Site_106    4   Port 3-4    4

Site_106    4   Port 5-6    4

Site_106    5   Port 1-2    1

Site_106    5   Port 3-4    7

Site_106    5   Port 5-6    7

Site_106    6   Port 1-2    10

Site_106    6   Port 3-4    7

Site_106    6   Port 5-6    7

Site_106    7   Port 1-8    4

Site_106    8   Port 1-8    1

Site_106    9   Port 1-8    3

I would like to build a query that would produce this:

Site ID Antenna ID  Controller 1    Controller 1 Electrical Tilt    Controller 2    Controller 2 Electrical Tilt    Controller 3    Controller 3 Electrical Tilt

Site_106    3   Port 1-2    4   Port 3-4    4

Site_106    4   Port 1-2    1   Port 3-4    4   Port 5-6    4

Site_106    5   Port 1-2    1   Port 3-4    7   Port 5-6    7

Site_106    6   Port 1-2    10  Port 3-4    7   Port 5-6    7

Site_106    7   Port 1-8    4

Site_106    8   Port 1-8    1

Site_106    9   Port 1-8    3

I also need the query to be source for a subform. Using a crosstab query, I got somewhat close to the format I wanted, but then couldn't use that query as source for a subform.

Thanks.

[image: How I would like to see the data]

Comment: Can you tidy up your data?  It's really had to read now.

Comment: You can use a crosstab in a subform, you just cannot edit the results.

Comment: Sorry, realized the formatting was strange after posting. Tried to post pictures, but it won't let me do that as I'm new. Cleaned it up the best I could figure how to, but it still looks a little strange. I hope it makes sense. If you have any tips on how to post data from Excel, I'd be happy to edit the data. Thanks!

Comment: @Fionnuala Thanks for your reply, however, when I try to use the crosstab query as source for a subform, I get the following message and no data displays in the subform "You can't use a pass-through query or a non-fixed-column crosstab query as a record source for a subform or subreport. Before you bind the subform or subreport to a crosstab query, set the query's ColumnHeadings property.". Ideally, I'd like the data formatted a little differently anyway (as described ablove), but in the abscence of that, I could get by with a crosstab.

Comment: Set the source object of the subform to the name of the crosstab query eg `Query.Query1`

Comment: BTW, several crosstabs may solve your problems, you seem to have 3 crosstabs that can be joined on siteID and antennaId, it might be easier if controller was separated into the part before the dash (Port 1) and the part after the dash (2, 8)

Comment: .., if you had the additional fields, you would be down to two more sensible crosstabs.

Comment: @Fionnuala Thanks, I think that basically what I ended up doing. It took two crosstab queries and then a select query to bring them together. I'll post what I did. Please let me know if there is a cleaner or easier way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a select query first called qry_ControllerSequence:

SELECT t1.[Site ID], t1.[Antenna ID], "Controller " & Count(*) AS ControllerSequence, t1.[Electrical Controller], t1.[Electrical Tilt]
FROM Antenna_Electrical_Parameters AS t1 LEFT JOIN Antenna_Electrical_Parameters AS t2 ON (t2.[ID] <= t1.[ID]) AND (t2.[Site ID] = t1.[Site ID]) AND (t2.[Antenna ID] = t1.[Antenna ID])
GROUP BY t1.[Site ID], t1.[Antenna ID], t1.[Electrical Controller], t1.[Electrical Tilt];

Then two crosstab queries, the first called qry_ControllerPorts:

TRANSFORM First(qry_ControllerSequence.[Electrical Controller]) AS [FirstOfElectrical Controller]
SELECT qry_ControllerSequence.[Site ID], qry_ControllerSequence.[Antenna ID]
FROM qry_ControllerSequence
GROUP BY qry_ControllerSequence.[Site ID], qry_ControllerSequence.[Antenna ID]
PIVOT qry_ControllerSequence.ControllerSequence In ("Controller 1","Controller 2","Controller 3","Controller 4");

And the second called qry_ControllerET:

TRANSFORM First(qry_ControllerSequence.[Electrical Tilt]) AS [FirstOfElectrical Tilt]
SELECT qry_ControllerSequence.[Site ID], qry_ControllerSequence.[Antenna ID]
FROM qry_ControllerSequence
GROUP BY qry_ControllerSequence.[Site ID], qry_ControllerSequence.[Antenna ID]
PIVOT qry_ControllerSequence.ControllerSequence In ("Controller 1","Controller 2","Controller 3","Controller 4");

Then used a select query to bring them together:

SELECT qry_ControllerPorts.[Site ID], qry_ControllerPorts.[Antenna ID], qry_ControllerPorts.[Controller 1], qry_ControllerET.[Controller 1] AS [Controller 1 ET], qry_ControllerPorts.[Controller 2], qry_ControllerET.[Controller 2] AS [Controller 2 ET], qry_ControllerPorts.[Controller 3], qry_ControllerET.[Controller 3] AS [Controller 3 ET], qry_ControllerPorts.[Controller 4], qry_ControllerET.[Controller 4] AS [Controller 4 ET]
FROM qry_ControllerPorts INNER JOIN qry_ControllerET ON (qry_ControllerPorts.[Antenna ID] = qry_ControllerET.[Antenna ID]) AND (qry_ControllerPorts.[Site ID] = qry_ControllerET.[Site ID]);

It wouldn't let me use the select query as source for a subform until after adding "In ("Controller 1","Controller 2","Controller 3","Controller 4")" to the PIVOT function at the end of the crosstab queries (as shown in the code above).

If anyone knows of an easier or cleaner way of doing this, please let me know. Otherwise, this solution works.

Thanks.